# I can't display the items from an array in an ejs view

Tags: javascript, html

Attached is a node.js route for displaying product data for the product ids that a user enters in an html form. In this route, I have the array 'prod_id_arr' with product ids. For each prod_id in this array, I select the mysql product database row and add it to another array 'data'. I then use the 'data' array to display the product data in "prod_multi_upd_pg" view at the end. When I console.log the data array, I see it is populated. However, it fails in the "prod_multi_upd_pg" view with the message "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'prod_id')". Interesting thing is that when I assign a single occurrence of the data array (i.e. data[0] or data[1]) to another array adata and pass the adata array to the ejs view, it works for that single item. I don't understand how js logic works, it is very confusing. What do I have to do to display all items? Any help will be appreciated.

```js
// Route to display current data for multiple product updates. 
app.get('/prod_multi_upd_pg', async (req, res) => {
    let prod_id_arr = req.query.prod_id_arr.split(','); 
    try {
        const dataPromises = prod_id_arr.map(prod_id => fetchData(prod_id)); 
        let results = await Promise.all(dataPromises);
        let data = results
            .filter(result => result !== null) // Remove null values
            .flat() // Flatten the array of arrays into a single array
            //.map(result => result[0]); // If I remove this line, it works.
        res.render("prod_multi_upd_pg", {data});
    } catch (error) {
        alert("Ürün kodu bulunamadı, lütfen geçerli bir ürün kodu girin.");
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
})
const fetchData = async (prod_id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_id = ?', [prod_id], function(err, row) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(row.length === 0 ? null : row);
            }   
        });
    }); 
};
```

```html
<tbody>
              <% if(data.length){for(let i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {%>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%=data[i].prod_id%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].saleprice%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].stock_quantity%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].max_order_qty%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].time_to_cargo%></td>
                  </tr> 
              <%} }else{ %>
```

Comment: Can you sure all prod_id have data? Because ```resolve(row.length === 0 ? null : row);``` will return null when don't have any product map with product_id and you can't access attribute of null. Item 0, item 1 may be happy cases.

Comment: @BehranMeydaner I have edited the answer both the ejs and js code. Try them and let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer in comment, I maybe understand your problem.

If you use another array (adata) and pass it to render function like this:

```js
res.render("prod_multi_upd_pg", { adata });
```

It mean you are passing the data for ejs format like this:

```
{
 adata: [...],
}
```

And in your ejs template, you checked if(data.length) pass, the data will be render. So the condition is False (Don't have any key 'data' in your argument), the result is a blank html without error.

And with `res.render("prod_multi_upd_pg", {data});`
In your data has some value are null because of `resolve(row.length === 0 ? null : row);`

So you can add a condition, like this:

```
 <% if(data.length){for(let i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {%>if(data[i]){
                  <tr>
                    <td><%=data[i].prod_id%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].saleprice%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].stock_quantity%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].max_order_qty%></td>
                    <td><%=data[i].time_to_cargo%></td>
                  </tr>}
              <%}
```

Hope it's helpfull.

Comment: Yusof and Dat, thank you both for your help. Yusof, I made the change but it made no difference.  And Dat,  I no longer get 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'prod_id')' error but I still can't display the product data. I enter 3 product ids but somehow js ignores them and shows the data array as empty. With js it is so frustrating, js error messages aren't helpful, it seems like doing the most basic tasks can turn into a nightmare. Sometimes i wonder if I should continue with node.js or if I should learn Java or Python or  something else.

Comment: I think the problem come from your data. Don’t have any product matching with 3 prods id.

Comment: I revised the code as indicated. Now the data.length is logged as 8, not 0.  And when I console.log data array, I see that data is there. But now I am back to the first problem where I get the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'prod_id')".  Also, as before, when I assign a single occurrence of the results array (i.e. results[0] or results[1]) to data array and pass the data array to the ejs view, it works for that single item. But I need to display all items. Further help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the array of 8 items?

Comment: I have added them to the body of my question.

Comment: replace ```let data = results;``` by ```let data = results.flat().filter(item => item !== null);```.

Comment: Hi Dat. That is the way I had it before and it didn't help and I removed the filtering all together. Now I put the filtering back in as you suggest but this time it goes staraight to the catch section where it throws the '(500) Internal Server Error'.

Answer (score 1):

Problems in Your Code:

1. Incorrect Data Structure Handling.
2. Misinterpretation of Promise Resolution.

---

How to Fix the Problems:

1. Flatten the Nested Arrays.
2. Filter Out Null Values.

---

The Fixed Code:

```
app.get('/prod_multi_upd_pg', async (req, res) => {
    let prod_id_arr = req.query.prod_id_arr.split(',');
    try {
        const dataPromises = prod_id_arr.map(prod_id => fetchData(prod_id));
        let results = await Promise.all(dataPromises);

        // Flatten nested arrays and filter out null values
        let data = results
          .filter(result => result !== null) // Remove null values
          .flat() // Flatten the array of arrays into a single array
          .map(result => result[0]); // Assuming each query returns an array of one product

        console.log("Filtered and flattened data: ", data);
        console.log("Filtered and flattened data.length: ", data.length);

        res.render("prod_multi_upd_pg", { data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching product data: ", error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
});

const fetchData = async (prod_id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE prod_id = ?', [prod_id], function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(rows.length === 0 ? null : rows);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

```
<tbody>
    <% if(data.length) { %>
        <% for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
            <% if(data[i] !== null) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= data[i].prod_id %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i].saleprice %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i].stock_quantity %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i].max_order_qty %></td>
                    <td><%= data[i].time_to_cargo %></td>
                </tr> 
            <% } else { %>
                <!-- Optionally handle null entries here -->
            <% } %>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I added console.log statements for debugging. Can you please provide the outputs so I can check?

Comment: Can you replace it with this please? let data = results.flat().filter(item => item !== null && item.length > 0); // Keeps the array of product objects directly

Comment: Hi Yusof. I have tried your last code and it didn't help. Now it goes to catch error section where it throws error "(500) Internal Server Error". Also, following is the node.js output.    Server has started on port number 3000
Filtered and flattened data:  [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
Filtered and flattened data.length:  3   It looks like the data array entries are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out this nasty and persistant problem. The culprit was the line  ".map(result => result[0])" in the try block. When I remove it, it works. I thank everyone who tried to help. This question can now be closed.